# External global variables strange issue IAR

Tags: c, linker, global-variables, extern, cpu-registers

I'm currently developing a project for an AVR ATMega8 microcontroller. Let's say I have multiple files:

init.c:

```
__no_init __regvar unsigned char flags@ 4; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char tb_flags@ 5; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char st_flags@ 6; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char dp_flags@ 7; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char g83_flags@ 8; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char ms_flags@ 9; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char co_flags@ 10; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char tm_cs5460@ 11; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char tm_noZX@ 12; 
__no_init __regvar unsigned char tm_state@ 13;
```

With that code I tell the compiler I want to use registers to store global variables (memmory optimization). This file includes the next one, Defines.h

Defines.h:

```
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char flags@ 4; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char tb_flags@ 5; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char st_flags@ 6; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char dp_flags@ 7; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char g83_flags@ 8; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char ms_flags@ 9; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char co_flags@ 10; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char tm_cs5460@ 11; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char tm_noZX@ 12; 
extern __no_init __regvar unsigned char tm_state@ 13;
```

I do this because defines.h is included from every file in my project. With that I thought that the scope of all the global variables was the whole project but I'm getting an strange error:

```
Error[e46]: Undefined external "st_flags" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 ) 
Error[e46]: Undefined external "dp_flags" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 ) 
Error[e46]: Undefined external "g83_flags" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 ) 
Error[e46]: Undefined external "flags" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 ) 
Error[e46]: Undefined external "co_flags" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 ) 
Error[e46]: Undefined external "tm_noZX" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 ) 
Error[e46]: Undefined external "tm_state" referred in main ( C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\CentroStirling\Progreso\MSUIAR\Debug\Obj\main.r90 )
```

If you look carefully, there are 10 globals and only 7 errors. That means some of them are being recognized...

What could I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure some of them are being recognized? Perhaps you have not used these variables outside their defining file, and thus they need not be linked.

Comment: in main I give a value to all the variables just to test

Comment: [This thread](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=10398&start=0) talks about the need to also inform the compiler that you want to "lock" a certain number of registers, perhaps you haven't done that.